# Fill a matrix from a file in C

Tags: c, matrix, file-io

I'm trying to write a little program that read from a file. I tryied this codes from a file (random.dat) that contains the following numbers:

```
0.575 0.235
0.456 0.322
```

The code that I wrote is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 2

int main (void) {
  FILE *fp;
  int i, j;
  double x,y,data[N][N] = {{0}};

  if ((fp = fopen("random.dat", "r")) == NULL ) {
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  fp = fopen("random.dat","r");
  printf("\n");

  for (i=0;i<N;i++){
    fscanf(fp,"%lf",&x);
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
      fscanf(fp,"%lf",&x); 
      data[i][j] = x;
      printf("data[%d][%d]=%lf\n",i,j,data[i][j]);  
    }   
  }
  printf("\n");
  fclose(fp);
return(0);
}
```

Does the code is well written?

I don't understand why the terminal write:

```
data[0][0]=0.235000
data[0][1]=0.465000
data[1][0]=0.322000
data[1][1]=0.322000
```

Instead of:

```
data[0][0]=0.575000
data[0][1]=0.235000
data[1][0]=0.465000
data[1][1]=0.322000
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Well, considering that your code has poor formatting by any standard, generates several warnings, and isn't very standard-compliant, I'd put it firmly in the 'not well written' camp.  If, in addition, it doesn't seem to work, then no, I guess it really isn't well written.

Comment: "Does the code is well written?" - the fact you omitted the return type of `main()` returns false for that assertion already on the 4th line.

Comment: My terminal doesn t give me any warning nor errors... anyway i ll edit the code with a `int main (void)` and a `return(0)` if it gives you problems...

Comment: I'm not going to go into the errors you're getting -- most of them are actually being caused by your style.  As an afterthought, I would go ahead and post this on the [Code Review StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once you have your functional errors sorted.

Comment: @Valerio, you also have an unused variable `y`, so that would warn too, though maybe you need to turn up the warnings setting you pass to your compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace statements,

```
for (i=0;i<N;i++){
   fscanf(fp,"%lf",&x);
   for(j=0;j<N;j++){
     fscanf(fp,"%lf",&x); 
     data[i][j] = x;
     printf("data[%d][%d]=%lf\n",i,j,data[i][j]);  
   }   
}
```

with

```
 for (i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&x);
        data[i][j] = x;
        printf("data[%d][%d]=%lf\n",i,j,data[i][j]);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this nested loop (reformatted to be easier to read):

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    fscanf(fp, "%lf", &x);   // first fscanf

    for(j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &x); // second fscanf
        data[i][j] = x;
        printf("data[%d][%d]=%lf\n", i, j, data[i][j]);  
    }    
}
```

You'll see that the inner loop immediately overwrites the `x` value read in your outer loop.  That means you essentially skip reading the first number in the file entirely.  Later that causes one of the inner-loop `fscanf` calls to fail, but since you don't check the return value, your program doesn't notice.

Just delete the first `fscanf()` line and you'll be set.

As an editorial aside, if you step through your program with a debugger, you'd see this problem happening immediately.

Comment: and also why fopen("random.dat","r"); two times ??

Comment: it should be a control to see if there is or not the file to read

Comment: @Valerio, you don't have to do it twice to find that out.

Comment: @Carl Ok thanks, I m still at the begging, I ll take it as a good advice, thank you!